# How to add links in device settings for our app?

Tags: ios, ipad, application-settings, settings.bundle

I have to add my website link in iPad settings for our app. I know how to add simple text but don't know how to add links so that clicking on it safari will open.

Same as done in `facebook` / `twitter` app for "learn more about facebook/twitter"

I have checked [this url](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) but didn't find how to add URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code to your action method of setting row/button

```
NSURL *yourLinkURL = [[NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.google.co.in" ];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: yourLinkURL];
```

Comment: wanted to add link in iPad setting dear

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the settings bundle. The only reason Facebook and Twitter have it is because they are more integrated with the system, so they run a special settings bundle that normal developers don't have access to.